# Mysql -race condition during REPLACE possible?

Tags: mysql

I am sorry for the minimalistic question, the manual doesn't tell much about it.
REPLACE INTO is calling a DELETE (if required) and an INSERT on the primary key on inserting.

Now what I wonder: Is there actually a time where SELECT will not return a result for the affected primary which is being replaced ?

When doing INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ... I would expect: there is no race condition, it's always accessible.
However if I imagine DELETE, INSERT, it might be different.

Any expert knows about that ?

Comment: If there's any concern about things like this, do them in a transaction. That will guarantee there's no intermingling effects until the transaction is committed.

Comment: By default, each query automatically runs in a transaction. So it should be safe. But using explicit transactions is the best way to be sure.

Comment: hm ok, so it should actually not be possible to "race" if it's in a transaction by default.